# Can U-SQL EXTRACT Column Definition be specified as Table Type

Tags: extract, u-sql

I have defined a Table Type and wanted to use that with the EXTRACT statement instead of defining the same structure again as part of the EXTRACT. It doesn't seem to work for me, and documentation doesn't indicate if this is supported.

Thanks,
Nasir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported but it is on our backlog. You can add your supporting vote to the following feedback item:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/10732041-allow-me-to-define-a-schema-that-i-can-reuse-in-mu